# UIButton - changing frame alters response to touches

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

I have a UIButton. I found that when I moved it, it no longer responded to touches. Let me explain in detail how I determined this: when I shift a 100pixel width button by 50 pixels to the right, only the left half responded to my finger tapping it.

How do I tell the button "update your touches checker" when I dynamically change the frame of it? I am changing the frame in code, NOT in xib.

Initialization:

```
    MATCGlossyButton *repeat = [[MATCGlossyButton alloc] init];
    [repeat addTarget:self action:@selector(repeatPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [repeat setTitle:@"Repeat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    repeat.buttonColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    repeat.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    repeat.cornerRadius = 20;
    repeat.frame = CGRectMake(200,208,105,50);
```

And then later on:

```
repeat.frame = CGRectMake(265, 208, 105, 50);
```

Comment: Are you changing it in code or in the IB?

Comment: Then please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are moving the button beyond the bounds of its parent view?  Even if clipping is off, touches aren't propagated outside of a view.

An easy way to visualise the borders of your views is to do the folowing:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

[...]

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Yeah the layer was wrong. There was a red line right in the middle of the button. I tried changing self.view.frame and self.view.layer.frame to fit my landscape screen properly, and the red line is fixed. But! The button still doesn't respond on the right half.